# What can I do in case of PHP memory overflow?

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I maintain my own managed server with php7.3. Every few days my website is suddenly unavailable.

My server hoster said that the PHP processes for the domain were used up and therefore the site was not accessible.

The only recent change in php.ini is opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 64 (previously 8).

- Can this be the reason?
- How can I prevent the PHP processes from overflowing or what do I have to do to ensure that the PHP processes are automatically terminated in the event of an overload or that the server restarts in such a case?

Comment: Try putting opcache.interned_strings_buffer back to 8 MB and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have access to your server logs (Apache/nginx, PHP), if yes, check them. What does "*suddenly unavailable*" mean - errors?  No response at all? What exactly does the browser say? If the server is managed as you say, the support should give you some more technical info to start troubleshooting with ...

Comment: There is no error message at all. The site remains white. Unfortunately the apache server log was disabled.

Comment: Did you try searching for "PHP white screen"?  There are lots of answers here about what to do to find more info, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php ... Have you re-enabled your Apache logging?